# Five-Minute Comics: Part 1

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

[image]

Puzzles made in 5 minutes or less.

brought to you by having like an hour, but too committed to break my streak now

Comment: Lacking a hyphen, the written title indicates that there are 5 small puzzles, but there are 6!

Comment: It’d also imply my time limit were four minutes less... good thing there IS that dash though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Top left

> These are all clues with the subscripts enumerating the answers:
>  -- / -- BE
>  C / O / AC
>  A / BED / D
>  There are two of each letter, A-E. Read these as flag semaphore to get **MERGE**.

## Top right

> The three categories are "words that can come before BOARD", "words that can come before CRAFT" , and "words that can come before TEXT". The middle word is **HOVER**.

## Middle left

> This is a cryptic clue: "Trump supporter, debatably" is PUTIN, and switching sides makes that into **INPUT** (with definition "gave advice to").

## Middle

> The shapes of these objects are letters spelling out **MOUSE**.

## Bottom left

> This is a rebus: MINER + VENTS - NERVE = **MINTS**.

## Bottom right

> A `LARGE INTESTINE` is a "colon", and an `ERA` is a "period" (the bottom half of a colon, as in punctuation marks). The second part is a "semicolon" since it's half of the clue for colon, so the corresponding word is **COMMA**.

## Final message

> Each puzzle has five numbers below it. Match each five-letter answer to five numbers, then read off the numbers in order from 1 to 30 to get "**UMMM SOME CREATIVE PUN OR SOMETHING**".

Answer (score 3):

**02 28 19 26 05:**

> A rebus. MINER+VENTS-NERVE = **MINTS**.

**07 16 10 30 25: (solved by Deusovi)**

> Superscript number is the enumeration:
>  `-  - BE`
>  `C  O AC`
>  `A BED D`
>  notice there are five pairs of letters. Treating their positions as flag semaphore and decoding gives **MERGE**.

**03 20 18 22 11:**

> Take the shape of each of the items. Kitten's ears are an M, cueball is O, cup is U, snake is S, trident on its side is E. Together, they give **MOUSE**.

**27 06 15 08 21:**

> Venn diagram. Upper left circle is words that can come before BOARD, upper right is before CRAFT, bottom is before TEXT. The word that can come before all three is **HOVER**.

**Meta (partial):**

> Looks like a simple crostic style thing. For example, for HOVER, H goes in position 27, O in position 6, V in position 15, etc.
>  String so far is ?MM?S OME?R E???V E?UNO RS??E THI?G

Comment: ah, your rebus attempt is probably right

Comment: Yours isn't bad though. The one I put seems to be a little more elegant IMO.